# ¿Como llamar a una clase de otro proyecto?

Tags: java, eclipse

Me gustaría saber como puedo llamar a una clase java desde otro proyecto.
He probado a añadir el proyecto mediante el Java Build Path, y si que podía acceder a los getters y los setters tras la importación de la clase, pero cuando ejecuto el programa, me sale el siguiente error:

```
Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: XXXX
```

Alguien me puede orientar en este tema?

**UPDATE:**

Tras los comentarios, no uso maven, dado que es un proyecto el cual estoy empezando a mantener, el qual tiene 15 años.
Este proyecto consta de dos partes

1. Web
2. Fachada

Si accedo a un fichero de la parte Web, y voy a Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path, en la pestaña de Projects, está añadido el proyecto de Fachada, para poder acceder a las clases de este proyecto.

Ahora, quiero acceder desde la Fachada, a una clase que está en la parte Web, para ello, voy a roject -> Properties -> Java Build Path, en la pestaña de Projects, añado el proyecto de Web, y puedo hacer el import de la clase correspondiente, así como acceder a los getters y setters oportunos, pero voy a cargar la web para ver el funcionamiento y ver si funciona, me sale el error anteriormente descrito.

Para obtener los datos cargados, los obtengo de la sesión:

```
DatosWeb datos = (DatosWeb)request.getSession().getAttribute("datos");
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sin saber cómo está montado el proyecto (Usas Maven?) y sin ver el código es complicado ayudarte, ese error parece corresponder a un estado http 404 que **no** tiene que ver con el problema que comentas. Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida y leer [ask]

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con una mejor explicación.

Comment: Creo que es un problema de diseño. Según lo entiendo, tiene sentido que desde el proyecto Web puedas ver las clases de la fachada, ya que seguramente desde la Web llamas funciones hechas en la fachada, sin embargo creo que hacer lo contrario (ver objetos del Web desde la fachada) es incorrecto, estarías creando una dependencia circular.